# How I can display the application name on the "display name" column on tomcat server?

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm working on a java mid-level app, and I need to deploy it onto a tomcat server. My problem is that when I deployed the app on the tomcat server, the name is not showing in the column "display name". How do I display the application name in this column ?

Answer (score 2):

In your web.xml you need:

```
  <display-name>Your App Display Name</display-name>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I edited my web.xml. Now the other problem that I have is in the column of "Running" on tomcat, it gave me a false value. you know how I can fix this problem?    Thanks

Comment: I did that before, but gave me the fallowing error:                  FAIL - Application at context path /FPADepot_5.1 could not be started

Comment: @Edwin check your Tomcat log files, if you have trouble interpreting them, generate another question.

Answer (score 1):

**Display Name** - The display name for the web application if it has one configured in its "`web.xml`" file.

Type here.

```
<display-name>Application Display Name</display-name>
```